# Errors with turning string into integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay so I'm reading in these values, I used type(value) to figure out that they are being read in as strings. so I tried to convert them to integers. Here is what I have:

```
with open('sextractordata1488.csv') as f:
    #getting rid of title, aka unusable lines:
    for _ in xrange(15):
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split()
        object_num = int(float(cols[0]))
```

and received this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: #
```

I also tried

```
int(cols[0])
```

and received this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'
```

why is it giving me #? I read that this means that some of the values are text, but they're not. They're all numbers. It gives me this error for every line, and every line is a number.

Someone wanted me to copy and paste a sample of the data, here it is without the first 16 lines that I removed and with ... to indicate that there are many more columns of data there just wasn't room:

```
     1  -7.9031   0.0364     13.69501    489.4349...
     2  -6.5735   0.1097     13.69501    193.0220...
     3  -6.4870   0.1184     13.69501    192.5962...
     4  -7.6035   0.0462     13.69501    504.2180...
     5  -7.4926   0.0506     13.69501    782.2051...
     6  -7.6036   0.0462     13.69501    569.3883...
```

Sorry if there's an easier way to show that. I'm new to the site.

Comment: Try printing `cols` before you set `object_num` and see what it says

Comment: A string is casted to `int` only if the given string is composed of digits, So `"12345"` can be casted to `int`, `"123Abv"` cannot be, And as the error says the given string has `"#"` which is not a valid digit. hence raises error

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data for us to look at directly from the file?

Comment: I notice you say in your question you removed the first 16 lines but in in your code you remove the first 15 lines. what's on the previous line?

Comment: I printed cols and it was just all of the values for what's listed above as the data in 'string format' like so, indicating that they're all strings.

Comment: You can't pass a string representation of a float to `int()`

Comment: I removed 16, because in programming 1 starts with 0, so its 0,1,2,...,15 but it's really 16 lines. When I print the first line after deleting it, it gives me the first line I really want, shown above, so I know that's not a mistake

Comment: No, you didn't. `xrange()` is exclusive on the `stop` parameter.  So in your code it goes from 0 to 14 for a total of 15 iterations.

Comment: Apparently that was the problem. It was actually reading it the 16th line even though it wasn't printing it for some reason. When I changed it to 16 everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the problem was in the xrange function. I put 15 when I should have put 16, so the first line had letters in it which was the problem.